# How to query table results with m,n-relationships to a different table with (unnecessarily) LEFT JOINs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

#### Please advise on a better formulation of the question.

## Basis

I have SQL tables *R=recipes, I=ingredients.* (minimum example):

- `R (id)`
- `RI (id, r_id, i_id)`
- `I (id, description)`
  where RI is intermediate table connecting R and I (otherwise in `m,n`-relationship).

#### You may skip this

In HTML I have an input for filtering recipes by ingredients. Input is sent to PHP with JavaScript's Fetch API (`body: JSON.stringify({ input: filter.value.trim() })`).

In PHP I clean it up and explode it into array of words so `%&/(Oh/$#/?Danny;:¤      boy!` gets converted to `['Oh', 'Danny', 'boy']`

```php
$filterParams = preg_replace('/[_\W]/', ' ', $data['input']);
$filterParams = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $filterParams);
$filterParams = trim($filterParams);
$filterParams = explode(' ', $filterParams);
```

## What I want

I need an SQL query for all recipe IDs that require *all* of the ingredients from the input. Consider these two recipes:

```
ID   RECIPE    INGREDIENTS
 1   pancake   egg, flour, milk
 2   egg       egg
```

Filtering for "eg, ilk" should only return 1 but not 2.

## What I have #1

This gives me all recipes that require *any* of the ingredients, therefore it returns 1 and 2.

```php
$recipeFilters = array_map(function ($param) {
    return "ri.description LIKE '%{$param}%'";
}, $filterParams);

$recipeFilter = implode(' OR ', $recipeFilters);

$selRecipes = <<<SQL

    SELECT DISTINCT rr.id
    FROM
        recipe_ingredient ri LEFT JOIN
        recipe_intermediate_ingredient_recipe riir ON riir.ingredient_id = ri.id LEFT JOIN
        recipe_recipe rr ON rr.id = riir.recipe_id
    WHERE
        {$recipeFilter} AND
        rr.id IS NOT NULL

SQL;

$recipes = data_select($selRecipes); // Custom function that prepares statement, binds data (not in this case), and eventually after all error checking returns $statement->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

$ids = [];
foreach ($recipes as $recipe)
    $ids[] = "{$recipe['id']}";
```

## What I have #2

Replacing `OR` with `AND` in the fifth line returns neither 1 nor 2, because no ingredient has both eggs and milk (ie. eg, ilk) in it's name.

```php
...
$recipeFilter = implode(' AND ', $recipeFilters);
...
```

## Suboptimal solution

I know I can simply query for each ingredient separately and then with some simple array manipulations get what I desire.

**Is it possible to do it in just one query, and how?**

Comment: read about mysql `having`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: I know, thanks for the warning. As I've said, my `data_select($query, ...$bindParams)` function handle all of that exactly (MySQLi, not PDO), I just wanted to make the code a bit more minimalistic here, instead of putting 3 extra lines in for getting values in the function (and replacing values shown with `?`. That being said, the as is allows only alphanumerics and spaces, so at least something like `OR 1=1` is out of the question, since `=` is removed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query with grouping in combination with `HAVING COUNT()` to get the desired result.

**recipe**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pancakes |
| 2 | eggs |

---

**ingredient**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | eggs |
| 2 | flour |
| 3 | milk |

---

**recipe_ingredient**

| rid | iid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

---

Consider this query:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name FROM recipe r
  JOIN recipe_ingredient ri ON r.id = ri.rid
  JOIN ingredient i ON i.id = ri.iid
WHERE i.name LIKE '%ilk%' OR i.name LIKE '%eg%'
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(i.name) = 2;
```

This query selects the recipes, joins the ingredients, and groups by recipe ID, using `HAVING COUNT(i.name)` to count the ingredients matching the `OR` filters, which gives you:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pancakes |

Comment: Thanks! Got it working for simple input as presented in question. Now I have a different problem. Having 2 ingredients with descriptions (names) `cow milk` `goat milk`, causes an issue if the input is "egg, cow milk". This make three parameters `['egg', 'cow', 'milk']` which breaks (not really breaks) the query on `HAVING COUNT()` line. Any workarounds?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure I understand the problem. It's the nature of the `LIKE` operator when using wildcards. I don't know your UI and how it is supposed to work, but if you replace the `LIKE` operations by exact match `=`, it should work. So, if you want to get all recipes with eggs and cow milk, you would use `WHERE i.name = 'cow milk' OR i.name = 'eggs'`. It might be a good idea to create a new question.

Comment: You could, for example, provide a search field with suggestions on the UI side (e.g. using a chip input component or similar). For the suggestions you query the `ingredients` table using the input text as the like filter. Selecting an entry then creates a chip with the full ingredient name, which then can be used for filtering in the final query (using the `=` operator).